# Not able to use ManagementObjectSearcher under Windows Service (Topshelf)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, topshelf

I have simple Windows Service (Topshelf) written in .NET. When I try to use ManagementObjectSearcher (specifically to search connected disk drives) I get error:

> The specified service does not exist as an installed service. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070424)

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");


 searcher.Get())
```

Everything else works fine (eg. using repository to access DB), only fails on this.

Comment: Could you add some code? What have you tried?

Comment: I just edited the original question. I have the same code functioning in Business consumer. The only problem is when I put it in Win Service.